# In angular modules why the body is the last array element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is more of an architectural question.

One of the most common forms of defining an angular module is this:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function Ctrl($scope) {
    //body...
}]);
```

But I don't find the syntax very intuitive. How about having the list of dependencies in an array like [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define):

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope'],
          function Ctrl($scope) {
            //body...
          });
```

This way the whole array will contain only string elements each of which refers to a module. The array matches the function parameters one by one. (kinda like `arguments`).

So my question is why Angular designers went for this convention?

Answer (score 3):

It kind of does that in a sense. you can do this by using `$inject`.

```
function SomeCtrl ($scope) {
  // do something with $scope
}

SomeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('SomeCtrl', SomeCtrl);
```

I am not a no Expert on this, but I did found a great post on how this process works and it might help answer your question: http://toddmotto.com/angular-js-dependency-injection-annotation-process/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know about `$inject` but I'm wondering why it is designed like that on the first place? I've read that link from Todd. It is more about *how* rather than *why*.

Comment: Totally understand, I was just hoping to shed some light on the issue.

Comment: I would personally post in AngularJS IRC.  I will keep on eye on this post and put it in there tomorrow afternoon.  A few people that work on the project hide out in there every so often ^_^

Comment: Yeah I'm going to +1 this anyway, but it would be great if someone from the Angular team elaborates what is the idea behind this syntax? Like the IRC idea but it's blocked from my work.

Comment: Just posted it in IRC; and will again tomorrow for you. Hope to hear back from someone on the team!

Comment: Thanks mate :) I'll be waiting to hear from you.